# Как ограничить вывод данных из массива?

Tags: php, foreach, if

```
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>

<?if (!empty($arResult)):?>
<ul id="horizontal-multilevel-menu" class="menu">

<?
$previousLevel = 0;
foreach($arResult as $arItem):
$strImg = '';

if(intval($arItem["PARAMS"]["PICTURE"])>0 && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]==2){
   $img = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arItem["PARAMS"]["PICTURE"], array('width'=>100, 'height'=>100),
 BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, false);  
   $strImg = '<img alt="" src="'.$img['src'].'" />';

 }
    ?>

    <?if ($previousLevel && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
        <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]));?>

    <?endif?>

    <?if ($arItem["IS_PARENT"]):?>

        <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>

            <li class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>active menu-item<?else:?>menu-item<?endif?>"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="item"><?=$strImg?><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
        <?else:?>

            <li<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?> class="sub-item item-selected"<?endif?>><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="parent"><?=$strImg?><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>

        <?endif?>
     <li class="sub-item">
        <a class="all-item" href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>">
          Все категории
        </a>
      </li>
    <?else:?>

        <?if ($arItem["PERMISSION"] > "D"):?>

            <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>

                <li class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>active menu-item<?else:?>menu-item<?endif?>"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="item"><?=$strImg?><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
            <?else:?>

                ******   <li<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?><?endif?> class="sub-item"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$strImg?><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li> *********

            <?endif?>

        <?else:?>

            <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
                <li  class="menu-item"><a href="" class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>root-item-selected<?else:?>root-item item<?endif?>" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$strImg?><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
            <?else:?>
                <li  class="menu-item"><a href="" class="denied" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$strImg?><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
            <?endif?>

        <?endif?>

    <?endif?>

    <?$previousLevel = $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"];?>

<?endforeach?>

<?if ($previousLevel > 1)://close last item tags?>
    <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel-1) );?>
<?endif?>

</ul>
<div class="menu-clear-left"></div>
<?endif?>
```

Добрый день, господа.
Подскажите, как ограничить вывод пункта li в сложносоставном массиве, пункт я отметил звездочками с обеих сторон. Идет выборка из массива, когда я пытаюсь обернуть еще в один массив строку со звездочками, в общем, ничего не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Ужасный вопрос в плане непонятности. За такое адские кододемоны утащат в программистский ад. Что значит "ограничить вывод пункта li"?
Из того, что понял, могу сказать только, что выделеное не будет выводится, если `$arItem["PERMISSION"]` будет меньше или равно "D". А вот как это должно понимать, я не знаю. Может, в условии должно быть

```
$arItem["PERMISSION"]!="D"
```

или

```
 $arItem["PERMISSION"]== "D"
```

?

Comment: За такое адские кододемоны утащат в программистский ад.  ))) Возьму на заметку. ))   
Это многоуровневые меню, идет вывод из массива данных, каталог -> раздел -> позиции.   
Цикл выводит все позиции из раздела, я хотел сделать вывод строго 20 позиций, пытался добавить еще одно условие с прерыванием, но не получилось, он мне то 20 разделов выведет то 20 каталогов, то 20 позиций одного типа. )))